# How to add object in a list of object in ne04j

Tags: java, neo4j-ogm

I have 2 classes as following

```
class Organization{
    @GraphId
    private Long Id;

    @Relationship(type = "has", direction="Outgoing)
    private List<Person> personList;
}
```

and

```
class Person{
    @GraphId
    private Long Id;
    private String name;  
}
```

and organization repo

```
interface OrganizationRepository extends GraphRepository<Organization> {}
```

I can Create `organization` and add list of `person` to it.

Now How can i add a new `person` to existing `organization`?

I can get all the person of a organization in a `list` and then add the new person to that list and then update the `organization`. but this does not seems the right way to do it.

So is there any other way to add a `person` to existing `organization`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, load the organization, add the person to the list, and save the organization.

**Edit based on comments:**

If the organization can contain 50,000 persons, then perhaps this is not the right model for you. How about a reference to the organization on the Person instead? Then, all you need to do is load the person, set his organization, and save the person.

Comment: It should be very resource hungry if i have like 50,000 students, loading it to the ram then update it. is it a good idea??

Comment: This is not the right way to design, I understand that. But I am just wondering if there is any other way to do this??

Comment: You can do this via a custom query too, but that defeats the purpose of the OGM if you would use a custom query to persist all data